# php add folder function based on username working, but only after I add another user

Tags: php, mkdir

Have been researching this for a day and can't figure it out. I am able to successfully create a folder when a user signs in that assigns it the username from the registration using mkdir(). The problem is, that I have to sign up another user before the first user's folder is added to my hosting, so the latest user never has a folder added until another user registers.

I am starting a new company so just testing it out myself and working from the bottom up, so I know I need to add more security to what I have, but I want to make sure I get this figured out before I move on.

Everything I have researched online and at php.net doesn't note anything I would need to add (that I can find).

Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you for the help.

Here is the code I have.

```
<?php 
       $author=$_POST['username'];
        $root = "upload";

 mkdir("$root/$author", 0777, true); 
?>
```

Thank you all again for the help.

Comment: Try running "clearstatcache();" before and after mkdir... Ive seen things be ignored because they are not known to phps file cache before now.

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue. Here is now the code I have.<?php 
     $author=$_POST['username'];
  $root = "upload";
     clearstatcache();
   mkdir("$root/$author", 0777, true); 
   clearstatcache();
    ?>

Comment: Debug it... echo out $author and $root before you create the directory and see what they are showing you.

Comment: What OS are you working on? What version of PHP? And what are the permissions on that folder?

Comment: OS is Linux, PHP5 (my GoDaddy account has php5.ini), and permissions are the default admin permissions that GoDaddy has. I am not sure if it is a permissions issue because the folders are added, only after another "user" registers. I get an API error at times on the hosting, not sure if that would be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, try the following and post back.

```
<?php

$author = $_POST['username'];
$root = "upload";
$path = $root.'/'.$author;

mkdir($path, 0777, true);
clearstatcache();

if(file_exists($path)){
  echo $path.' -> directory does exists';
} else {
  echo $path.' -> directory does not exist';
}

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget that POST values should ALWAYS be sanitized

Comment: Oh totally agree, just hashing out his problem at the moment. He knows already security is an issue... Remember that everyone!

Comment: So I did that and now nothing will post to my hosting. I get the following but the part about the file exists doesn't make sense to me because the folder value is based on the new username added, which is $author that is based on the unique username when signing up and I know for sure when testing the usernames I add are not already used, so there is no way the $author value could exist. This warning shows up as soon as I load my signup page:  `Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /home/content/14/6467414/html/upub/signup.php on line 105
upload/ -> directory does exists`.

Comment: The idea with that snippet, was to create a folder and see if it exists immediatly afterwards. What the result shows "upload/ -> directory does exists"... Look at the path "upload/", this shows that the $author was empty at the time of folder creation.